# Shrink down code complexity of a method

Tags: ruby

Actually i'm using this method, to replace a given content of a file:

```
def self.fix_authorgroup_work(title, name, email_business, company_name, company_division)
    agroup = "#{title}/de-DE/Author_Group.xml"
    namechomp = name.chomp
    # @note Split the variable to the array title[*]
    name = namechomp.split(' ')
    firstname = name[0]
    surname = name[1]
    # @note Author Group: Change the default stuff to the present user
    puts 'Replace the default content with the new content from the user (Authors_Group)'.color(:yellow)
    text = File.read(agroup)
    vorname = text.gsub('Enter your first name here.', "#{firstname}")
    puts vorname
    File.open(agroup, 'w') { |file|
      file.puts vorname
    }
    text = File.read(agroup)
    nachname = text.gsub('Enter your surname here.', "#{surname}")
    puts nachname
    File.open(agroup, 'w') { |file|
      file.puts nachname
    }
    text = File.read(agroup)
    email = text.gsub('Enter your email address here.', "#{email_business}")
    puts email
    File.open(agroup, 'w') { |file|
      file.puts email
    }
    text = File.read(agroup)
    member = text.gsub('Initial creation by publican', 'Initial creation')
    puts member
    File.open(agroup, 'w') { |file|
      file.puts member
    }
    text = File.read(agroup)

    org = text.gsub('Enter your organisation\'s name here.', "#{company_name}")
    puts org
    File.open(agroup, 'w') { |file|
      file.puts org
    }
    text = File.read(agroup)
    div = text.gsub('Enter your organisational division here.', "#{company_division}")
    puts div
    File.open(agroup, 'w') { |file|
      file.puts div
    }
```

So it looks a little bit complex. Maybe anyone can tell me, how to shrink down the code complexity? Sadly i havent done such thing earlier.

Comment: if you use a multiline block in ruby, use `do end` instead of `{}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could be solved with a good refactor like so:

```
def self.add_result(nice_description, value_name, agroup)
    text = File.read(agroup)
    new_value = text.gsub(nice_description, value_name)
    puts new_value
    File.open(agroup, 'w') { |file|
      file.puts new_value
    }
def self.fix_authorgroup_work(title, name, email_business, company_name, company_division)
    agroup = "#{title}/de-DE/Author_Group.xml"
    namechomp = name.chomp
    # @note Split the variable to the array title[*]
    name = namechomp.split(' ')
    firstname = name[0]
    surname = name[1]
    # @note Author Group: Change the default stuff to the present user
    puts 'Replace the default content with the new content from the user (Authors_Group)'.color(:yellow)
    add_result('Enter your first name here.', "#{firstname}", agroup)
    add_result('Enter your surname here.', "#{surname}", agroup)
    add_result('Enter your email address here.', "#{email_business}", agroup)
    add_result('Initial creation by publican', "Initial creation", agroup)
    add_result('Enter your organisation\'s name here.', "#{company_name}", agroup)
    add_result('Enter your organisational division here.', "#{company_division}", agroup)
```

Comment: Wooow. It looks many steps better than my. Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 2):

Daniel Slater's answer is a great one.

In addition you can also clean up your namechomp business from:

```
namechomp = name.chomp
name = namechomp.split(' ')
firstname = name[0]
surname = name[1]
```

to:

```
firstname, surname = name.chomp.split(' ')
```

Answer (score 0):

A good starting point would be to restructure this into a [Composed Method](https://www.rallydev.com/blog/engineering/clean-code-composed-methods).